# jquery show loading image until page loaded in div

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am trying to show a loading image every time the page loads into the div but I don't see the loading image.

I tried this:

```
<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading">
```

Jquery:

```
$('#content').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#loading').show();
    $('#content').load("about.php", function(){
        $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your `<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading">` outside of `#content` div.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing quotation-mark in your jQuery, after about.php.

This is the revised jQuery:

```
$('#content').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#loading').show();
    $('#content').load("about.php", function(){
         $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
         $('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```